# Pointer problem on external monitor

Tags: graphics, external-monitor, via

Pointer looks and work fine on laptop but when I connect external monitor it appears there as a shaking, square shape. Videos are not showing either.

my laptop hp 2133: 
Graphic card: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN896/VN896/P4M900, Chrome 9 HC.
System: Lubuntu 12.04

I think it is graphic problem but can't find drivers for my card and system.
I do have xserver-xorg-video-openchrome and disper installed.
I did not have that problem with Lubuntu 11.10.

My problem is a bit like :
[Mouse pointer strange problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21295/mouse-pointer-strange-problem)
but it was not solved so I decided to post my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a nice pointer:

Since now Lubuntu/Ubuntu does not have xorg.conf file I generated it (1) and then modify it to look like the one from Debian website (2) (http://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/HP/HP2133 )

1) generate xorg.conf:

press Ctrl+Alt+F1   (to switch to text terminal)

Login

**sudo service lightdm stop**   (to stop desktop environment)

**sudo xorg -configure**  (to configure xorg.conf, it will put the file in your home direction)

**sudo cp home/username/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf** (in username put your user name)  (to copy created file to the location that system will recognise and use it)

**sudo service lightdm start**   (to start desktop environment)

2) modify xorg.conf:

go to http://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/HP/HP2133 in section Resources Attachments there is xorg.conf file contents, select and copy it. (Ctrl+C copy selected)

Open terminal

**sudo leafpad /etc/X11/xorg.conf**    (to open xorg.conf for modification)

Ctrl+A  (to select all)

Delate   (to delele selected)

Ctrl+V    (to past copied earlier file)

Save and close file.

Restart computer.