Why mouse indicator moving with small mirror like image in Ubuntu jammy 22.04?
Why does the mouse indicator move with looks like small mirror image in Ubuntu 22.04?
Please find the below image for your reference.


will this help https://askubuntu.com/questions/21295/mouse-pointer-strange-problem

Which graphics card and driver are you using? Add that info by editing to your question.
